# error using std::make_shared() to construct an object with std::bind()

Tags: c++, std, boost-asio, bind, shared-ptr

I want to pass the parameter of `specify_local_address` and `specify_local_port` from `ClientService.cc` when constructing a new session object in `WebSocket.h`, but here I get an error when I add these two new parameters. It seems to require another parameter in the `std::make_shared()` function.

Code:

ClientService.cc

```
boost::asio::io_context ioc;
work_guard_type workGuard(ioc.get_executor());

string specify_local_address = "0.0.0.0";
unsigned short specify_local_portnumber = 46675;

info("In connection: client bind to local endpoint host {} port {}", specify_local_address, specify_local_portnumber);

// Launch the asynchronous operation

//here pass the parameters to session object
// construct a session with shared_ptr and pass the specify_local_address and specify_local_portnumber and OnRequest Callback function into the constructor
auto session = std::make_shared<WS::Client::session>(ioc, specify_local_address, specify_local_portnumber, std::bind(&ClientService::OnRequest, this, std::placeholders::_1));

this->service = session;
session->run(host.c_str(), reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(port), text);

// Run the I/O service. The call will return when
// the socket is closed.
ioc.run();


void ClientService::OnRequest(const std::string &msg) {
    if (msg.rfind("22", 0) != 0) {
        info("meta message: {}", msg);
        return;
    }


    Request req;

    try {
        ORB_SLAM2::toObject<Request>(req, msg);
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        error("parse request failed: {}", e.what());
        return;
    }

    if (req.path == "DistributeMap") {
        // update map on the client
        if (mpSLAM) {
            MapSlice slice;
            MapUpdater::Deserialize(slice, req.body);
            mpSLAM->GetMap()->UpdateMap(slice);
        }
    } else if (req.path == "PushMap") {
        if (mpSLAM) {
            // update map on the client
            MapSlice slice;
            MapUpdater::Deserialize(slice, req.body);
            mpSLAM->GetMap()->GetMapit()->ReceivePush(slice);
        }
    }
}
```

WebSocket.h

```
namespace Client {// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response

class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {

    websocket::stream <beast::tcp_stream> ws_;

    beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const std::string>> queue;
    std::string host_;
    std::uint8_t port_;
    std::function<void(const std::string&)> on_message;
    std::string localhost_;
    std::uint8_t localport_;

public:

    //here comes the constructor
explicit
    session(net::io_context &ioc, char const *localhost, unsigned int *localport, std::function<void(const std::string&)> on_message)
        : ws_(net::make_strand(ioc)), on_message(std::move(on_message))
    {

        localhost_ = localhost;
        localport_ = *localport;

        beast::error_code err;
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).bind(tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address_v4(specify_local_address), specify_local_portnumber));
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).socket().open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), err);
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).socket().bind(tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address_v4(localhost_), localport_));
    }
};

}
```

Build Log:

```
[1/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/slam_core.dir/code/src/ClientService.cc.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/slam_core.dir/code/src/ClientService.cc.o 
/usr/bin/c++ -DCOMPILEDWITHC11 -DSPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -Dslam_core_EXPORTS -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/home/ubuntu/SwarmMap/code -I/home/ubuntu/SwarmMap/code/include -I/home/ubuntu/SwarmMap/code/Thirdparty/popl -I/usr/include/eigen3 -isystem /usr/local/include/opencv -Wall -Wextra -DUSE_NVTX -Wno-deprecated-declarations -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=1 -std=c++11 -g -fPIC -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT CMakeFiles/slam_core.dir/code/src/ClientService.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/slam_core.dir/code/src/ClientService.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/slam_core.dir/code/src/ClientService.cc.o -c /home/ubuntu/SwarmMap/code/src/ClientService.cc
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/array:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/tuple:39,
                 from /home/ubuntu/SwarmMap/code/src/ClientService.cc:5:
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = ORB_SLAM2::WS::Client::session; _Args = {boost::asio::io_context&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, short unsigned int&, std::_Bind<void (ORB_SLAM2::ClientService::*(ORB_SLAM2::ClientService*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)>}; _Tp = ORB_SLAM2::WS::Client::session]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:   [ skipping 6 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:706:39:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp> std::make_shared(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = ORB_SLAM2::WS::Client::session; _Args = {boost::asio::io_context&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, short unsigned int&, std::_Bind<void (ORB_SLAM2::ClientService::*(ORB_SLAM2::ClientService*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)>}]’
/home/ubuntu/SwarmMap/code/src/ClientService.cc:63:127:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘ORB_SLAM2::WS::Client::session::session(boost::asio::io_context&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, short unsigned int&, std::_Bind<void (ORB_SLAM2::ClientService::*(ORB_SLAM2::ClientService*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/SwarmMap/code/include/ClientService.h:11:0,
                 from /home/ubuntu/SwarmMap/code/src/ClientService.cc:7:
/home/ubuntu/SwarmMap/code/include/WebSocket.h:72:9: note: candidate: ORB_SLAM2::WS::Client::session::session(boost::asio::io_context&, const char*, unsigned int*, std::function<void(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>)
         session(net::io_context &ioc, char const *localhost, unsigned int *localport, std::function<void(const std::string&)> on_message)
         ^~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/SwarmMap/code/include/WebSocket.h:72:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const char*’
/home/ubuntu/SwarmMap/code/include/WebSocket.h:51:7: note: candidate: ORB_SLAM2::WS::Client::session::session(ORB_SLAM2::WS::Client::session&&)
 class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
       ^~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/SwarmMap/code/include/WebSocket.h:51:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Does anyone know how to pass the parameter, and how to use `std::bind()` within `std::make_shared()`?

-----------updates---------------

Modified the type of the parameter to:

```
const std::string  specify_local_address = "0.0.0.0";
unsigned int  specify_local_portnumber = 46675;
```

Modified the make_shared to:

```
auto session = std::make_shared<WS::Client::session>(ioc, specify_local_address.c_str(), reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(specify_local_portnumber),
                                                     std::bind(&ClientService::OnRequest, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

These solved My problem, main problem is that I couldn't understand the build error in the log so I didn't know it is a type error then.

Comment: The second parameter of `session` constructor  is `char const*`, but you are passing `std::string`. The third is `unsigned int*`, but you are passing `unsigned short`. You haven't shown the declaration of `OnRequest`, so it's impossible to say whether your `bind` expression matches `std::function<void(const std::string&)>` parameter; but in any case, the other two mismatches are quite sufficient to render the code ill-formed.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks, It is indeed the type mistake you've mentioned, sorry for my careless fault and I didn't realize it is a type mistake when reading in Build Log then. Thanks for your responsive and helpful answer and hope you well.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).